# jQuery $().focus not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use jQuery's focus() method and I don't understand why it's not working. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3RGRv/4/

When you press "Ready to rock", the button handler is called and, inside of it, `$('#playlistNameInput').focus();`

The console logs messages acknowledging that this was reached and processed, but still no focus happens. Any idea why this is?

Comment: If the element isn’t displayed (or at least considered as part of the layout), it can’t be focused. Wait until your fade in animation finishes, then call `focus`. If that doesn’t work, I don’t know why. The combination of Backbone and jQuery is kind of hard to look at. P.S. `</button>` doesn’t close `<input>`

Comment: Side note: You should validate your HTML code, that will reveal plenty of potential problems. For example, a HTML document should have a `head` section, not a `header` section. http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: `<input> minutes </button>` LOL I think you forgot to delete `</button>` when you copied the code over.

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 setTimeout(function(){$('#playlistNameInput').focus();},500);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're first problem is that in `#step1` you've got random button end tags. `Input`s are self-closing.

Here's the cleaned-up version for step 1 and 2:

```
// Step 1
<input id="playlistNameInput" size="10">
that has at least <input id="totalHours" size="2"> hours and
<input id="totalMins" size="2"> minutes of music.</p> 
// Step 2
<input id="songTitle" placeholder="Title">
<input id="songArtist" placeholder="Artist">
<input id="songMinutes" placeholder="Minutes">
<input id="songSeconds" placeholder="Seconds">
```

Second, when you click "Ready to Rock", it takes you to `#step2`, which doesn't have `#playlistNameInput`.

Finally, move `$('#playlistNameInput').focus()` into the `fadeOut` so that it gets run *after* the next step is faded in.

```
$("#prompt").fadeOut('10000', function()
{
   $("#step1").css("visibility", "visible").hide().fadeIn('slow');
   $('#playlistNameInput').focus();
});
```

Done. Here's the [cleaned-up, working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3RGRv/5/).